# keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer methods for tensorflow.data.TextLineDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text, nlp

I have a very large text corpus which I am loading with:

```
text_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(list_files)
```

and cannot use the methods `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.fit_on_texts` or `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.fit_on_texts.texts_to_sequences` anymore because those methods require list of strings and not a tensorflow object. When testing my code, I used to convert the `text_ds` with:

```
input_data = list(map(tf.compat.as_str_any, list(text_ds.as_numpy_iterator())))#convert text_ds to a numpy list in binary format, and then convert elements of this list to python strings 
tokenizer_inputs = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, filters='')
tokenizer_inputs.fit_on_texts(input_data)#input_data is here a list of python strings 
input_sequences = tokenizer_inputs.texts_to_sequences(input_data)
```

But this procedure takes now too much time. How could I adapt my `text_ds` variable in a time-efficient way that it could be used on `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.fit_on_texts` and `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer.fit_on_texts.texts_to_sequences` ?

I have carefully looked at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#fit_on_texts) but wasn't able to find any answer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you apply Map() method on text_ds() .

like this -

```
def tokenrizer(data):
        tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
        return sequence
```

then apply

```
  text_ds.map(tokenizer)
```

Comment: I am sorry but this answer makes no sense. `fit_on_texts(data)` is precisely what my problem is: data must be a python list. It cannot be a tensorflow dataset object.

Comment: Hey train_ds is a tensorflow object but inside it there is python list. So when you apply map() method  on train_ds , It automatically fetch the list from tensorflow object..Whatever the operation you want to perform just make a function and pass it into map() method and apply on train_ds(which is your tensorflow object).

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work because the list does not contain python strings rather tensorflow strings which are binary encoded. For example doing 'list(text_ds.take(1).as_numpy_iterator())' returns '[b'produced by shin cine']', hence I get the error: 'AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'''